# NoSQL solution for persisting graphs at scale

Tags: python, nosql, graph-theory, networkx

I'm hooked on using Python and NetworkX for analyzing graphs and as I learn more I want to use more and more data (guess I'm becoming a data junkie :-).  Eventually I think my NetworkX graph (which is stored as a dict of dict) will exceed the memory on my system.  I know I can probably just add more memory but I was wondering if there was a way to instead integrate NetworkX with Hbase or a similar solution?

I looked around and couldn't really find anything but I also couldn't find anything related to allowing a simple MySQL backend as well.

Is this possible? Does anything exist to allow for connectivity to some kind of persistent storage?

### Update

I remember seeing this subject in 'Social Network Analysis for Startups', the author talks about other storage methods (including hbase, s3, etc..) but does not show how to do this or if its possible.

Comment: i edited the title of your Question and added the "nosql" tag. In particular, i removed the reference in the title to *networkx* because networkx doesn't require a particular graph format/protocol (in fact, it has methods for translating from/to all common formats), so the fact that your graphs are generated from networkx has no influence on the possible answers.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are two general types of containers for storing graphs:

1. **true graph databases:** e.g., *Neo4J*, *agamemnon*, *GraphDB*, and *AllegroGraph*; these not only store a graph but they also understand that a graph is, so for instance, you can query these
   databases e.g., *how many nodes are between the shortest path from
   node X and node Y*?
2. **static graph containers**: Twitter's MySQL-adapted FlockDB is the most well-known exemplar here. These DBs can store and retrieve
   graphs just fine; but to query the graph itself, you have to first
   retrieve the graph from the DB then use a library (e.g., Python's
   excellent Networkx) to query the graph itself.

The redis-based graph container i discuss below is in the second category, though apparently redis is also well-suited for containers in the first category as evidenced by [redis-graph](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis_graph/1.0), a remarkably small python package for implementing a graph database in redis.

**redis** will work beautifully here.

[Redis](http://www.redis.io) is a heavy-duty, durable data store suitable for production use, yet it's also simple enough to use for command-line analysis.

Redis is different than other databases in that it has multiple data structure types; the one i would recommend here is the ***hash*** data type. Using this redis data structure allows you to very closely mimic a "list of dictionaries", a conventional schema for storing graphs, in which each item in the list is a dictionary of edges keyed to the node from which those edges originate.

You need to first install [redis](http://www.redis.io) and the python client. The [DeGizmo Blog](http://degizmo.com/2010/03/22/getting-started-redis-and-python/) has an excellent "up-and-running" tutorial which includes a *step-by-step* guid on installing both.

Once redis and its python client are installed, *start a redis server*, which you do like so:

- *cd* to the directory in which you installed redis (*/usr/local/bin* on 'nix if you installed via *make install*); next
- type *redis-server* at the shell prompt then enter

you should now see the server log file tailing on your shell window

```
>>> import numpy as NP
>>> import networkx as NX

>>> # start a redis client & connect to the server:
>>> from redis import StrictRedis as redis
>>> r1 = redis(db=1, host="localhost", port=6379)
```

In the snippet below, i have stored a four-node graph; each line below calls *hmset* on the redis client and stores one node and the edges connected to that node ("0" => no edge, "1" => edge). (In practice, of course, you would abstract these repetitive calls in a function; here i'm showing each call because it's likely easier to understand that way.)

```
>>> r1.hmset("n1", {"n1": 0, "n2": 1, "n3": 1, "n4": 1})
      True

>>> r1.hmset("n2", {"n1": 1, "n2": 0, "n3": 0, "n4": 1})
      True

>>> r1.hmset("n3", {"n1": 1, "n2": 0, "n3": 0, "n4": 1})
      True

>>> r1.hmset("n4", {"n1": 0, "n2": 1, "n3": 1, "n4": 1})
      True

>>> # retrieve the edges for a given node:
>>> r1.hgetall("n2")
      {'n1': '1', 'n2': '0', 'n3': '0', 'n4': '1'}
```

Now that the graph is persisted, retrieve it from the redis DB as a NetworkX graph.

There are many ways to do this, below did it in *two* *steps*:

1. extract the data from the redis database into an *adjacency matrix*,
   implemented as a 2D NumPy array; then
2. convert that directly to a NetworkX graph using a NetworkX
   *built-in* function:

reduced to code, these two steps are:

```
>>> AM = NP.array([map(int, r1.hgetall(node).values()) for node in r1.keys("*")])
>>> # now convert this adjacency matrix back to a networkx graph:
>>> G = NX.from_numpy_matrix(am)

>>> # verify that G in fact holds the original graph:
>>> type(G)
      <class 'networkx.classes.graph.Graph'>
>>> G.nodes()
      [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> G.edges()
      [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

When you end a redis session, you can shut down the server from the client like so:

```
>>> r1.shutdown()
```

redis saves to disk just before it shuts down so this is a good way to ensure all writes were persisted.

So where is the redis DB? It is stored in the default location with the default file name, which is ***dump.rdb*** on your home directory.

To change this, edit the ***redis.conf*** file (included with the redis source distribution); go to the line starting with:

```
# The filename where to dump the DB
dbfilename dump.rdb
```

change dump.rdb to anything you wish, but leave the .rdb extension in place.

Next, to change the file path, find this line in redis.conf:

```
# Note that you must specify a directory here, not a file name
```

The line below that is the directory location for the redis database. Edit it so that it recites the location you want. Save your revisions and rename this file, but keep the .conf extension. You can store this config file anywhere you wish, just provide the full path and name of this custom config file on the same line when you start a redis server:

So the next time you start a redis server, you must do it like so (from the shell prompt:

```
$> cd /usr/local/bin    # or the directory in which you installed redis 

$> redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
```

Finally, the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis_graph/1.0) lists a package specifically for implementing a graph database in redis. The package is called [redis-graph](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19592#redis-graph-Graph-database-for-Python) and i have not used it.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.  Didn't know this was possible but I'll def play around with it.  Since you have answered alot of my graph related questions I am going to try to pick your brain with another..Do you know or have you tried to integrate networkx(or any graphing lib) with neo4j?  When I wrote this question I was thinking of redis but lately it seems neo4j is more optmized for graph related tasks..any thoughts on using neo4j with networkx(or jung,etc..)? I need to study very very large graphs(hundreds of millions of new nodes/day) & compare nodes/do pagerank,etc.

Comment: neo4j is a true graph database; what i implemented in my Answer is a "persisted graph". Both can store graphs; a graph db "understands" what a graph is, so it can be queried like "how many nodes are between nodes X and nodes Y? To do that in my redis implementation above you would need to first extract the graph from redis into e.g., networkx. In other words, neo4j (which is the only open-source graph db i know of) is like my redis implementation + a smart graph application layer (networkx). If you prefer to use Networkx, then that additional functionality might just get in the way.

Comment: Thank you so much Doug.  I think you have answered every graph question I have posted and sent me ever deeper into the interesting world of graphs.  I'm starting to see all my problems as graph problems but some of these problems datasets can get quite large.  This is sort of unrelated but as your very experienced in this space do you know networkx degrades as the graphs hit a certain size? Say it hits several billion nodes?  I'm doing my own testing but a bit conflicted because neo4j seems to do allot natively. Have you hit any road blocks in terms of graph sizes?

Comment: @Lostsoul : i'm pleased to hear my answer was useful to you. graph analysis using the db's own application layer versus 'conventional' two-step process is really just personal preference. Of course we know that computation on graphs is  (usually) inherently parallelizable--so for a dataset > 2GB, i would process it through Hadoop. This won't help with the dataset size issue, but have if not already aware of it, look at igraph (http://igraph.sourceforge.net/requirements.html) which is a lot faster than networkx, even using the python bindings.

Comment: You have def. helped me alot. I read a book on algos and thought of graphs but because of you I have read a few books dedicated to them(you recommended them) and got into networkx so big thanks! I'll look into igraph(never heard of it before).  I was experimenting with hbase as a datastore before but because I couldn't figure out how to get the graph structure onto it, I abandoned hbase(and hadoop) and instead was thinking of using redis(or neo4j) with something like rabbitmq to coordinated multiple servers processing those datasources.

Comment: I guess the problem I was thinking I would face is I didn't think I could parallelize graph algos that required the entire graph(such as pagerank) so I started to look for something that was aware of the entire graph(like your redis/networkx plugin or neo4j)..I'm not sure if thats a good approach but that was why I was asking this question, sort of as a starting point.

Comment: By the way, not sure if your interested(you may already know all the information here) but I believe you suggested a book to me called probabilistic graphical models by Koller(which was amazing) and she has a free Stanford class that started last week  www.pgm-class.org/
 Your answers and suggested def. have gotten me to follow the lectures(if it wasn't free, you should get a commission :-).

Comment: Thanks @Lostsoul and Doug for your very interesting conversation. My problem is pretty similar. I need to index a large graph (4GB), perform index lookup on nodes and compute the most central in specific subgraph (identified using breadfrist search algo).  I was wondering was you choice have been in the end ? Did you go for Reddis+NetworkX, neo4j, Python igraph or something else.  Again, performance is key here.  Thank you so much

Comment: Hi @Kevin. I ended up using spark. Partly because it looked so cool and also my developer friend had more experience with it.  http://spark.apache.org/

Comment: @doug: I've just been reading about Redis and am interested in graphs and so I came upon this great answer.  I have a question though: when you say "To do that in my redis implementation above you would need to first extract the graph from redis into e.g., networkx."... does this step involve copying memory for an entire graph from redis into the python process's memory?  Or is the whole point that it doesn't have to be copied?  Thanks

Comment: @user3391564 so a good pure python solution for persisting out-of-core graphs (while still being able to do computation on them) is HDF5 and the python bindings for HDF5, h5py (h5py.org); see this gist in my repo: https://gist.github.com/alexland/d011eeeb9724ff072a02

Comment: Thanks for the great efforts

Answer (score 5):

There is a SQLlite3 backed NetworkX implementation called Cloudlight.
https://www.assembla.com/spaces/cloudlight/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: Very nice, I can definitely make use of this!

Comment: Doesn't it support python 3 too?

Answer (score 1):

I would be interested to see the best way of using the hard drive. In the past I have made multiple graphs and saved them as .dot files. Then kind of mixed some of them in memory somehow. Not the best solution though.

```
from random import random
import networkx as nx

def make_graph():
    G=nx.DiGraph()
    N=10
    #make a random graph
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i):
            if 4*random()<1:
                G.add_edge(i,j)

    nx.write_dot(G,"savedgraph.dot")
    return G

try:
    G=nx.read_dot("savedgraph.dot")
except:
    G=make_graph() #This will fail if you don't use the same seed but have created the graph in the past. You could use the Singleton design pattern here.
print G.adj
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Robert.  I did think of this, as a worst case, to have a process that takes these flat files(which I know how to create) and pushes them to Hbase and then generates them on demand as well.  I don't think this is the best answer because sometimes the database exceeds the systems storage memory(which it will ultimately store this data as), if there's a way to have it constantly refer to the database than the memory problem is gone.

Comment: Yup, hopefully someone will post a better answer.

Comment: Your answer(and thought process) is great because as least there's a plan B in the worst case.  It shouldn't be too hard to send files to analysis that only limit the size of the data to the memory size(but I'd like to avoid that work if its already been done)