# How to Save graph in Python

Tags: python-3.x, data-analysis

Can we use something like this  plt.savefig('graph.graph')???

If not then what can be the proper way to save the graph at local storage but not in image or pdf format.
I want to store graphs.

Comment: so you want to store the values themselves?

Comment: Can you provide an example of code of what you are trying to accomplish which can be reproduced for the right answers to be given?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Store Graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19566247/6045800)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Matplotlib,

```py
savefig(fname, dpi=None, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w',
        orientation='portrait', papertype=None, format=None,
        transparent=False, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1,
        frameon=None, metadata=None)
```

refer the documentation to understand further:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html

Edit:

Refer this answer to store graph's data  [How to Store Graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566247/how-to-store-graphs)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO @Shaunak Deshpande! To get the best result and feedback, I recommend reading this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask